# How can i use socket.io globally in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

Currently I am using an API to get chatList, so the user cannot know if they have received a new msg. They have to refresh the page in order to know that there is a new message.

I am connecting with the socket when the user is in chat and they get disconnected with socket when they leave chat and move to some other page. 
But I want them to stay connected if they move to some other page.

Can you please guide me how can I achieve that? Is there any general socket available for applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io and webSocket connections cannot survive from one page to the next.  When you leave one page and go to another, all resources from the first page (including any webSocket or socket.io connections) will be closed.  That's how the browser works.

You can make a single page app (SPA) where the user clicks on things and the view changes, but it's just loading dynamic content into the same page so the actual web page never closes in the browser and thus the socket.io connection can persist.

Or, you can tag the user with a cookie so that when they leave the page, their connection closes and then they load another page and a new connection is established, your server can see that they are the same user that was just connected and your server can set things up appropriately for them to continue as if the connection was never redone.

> Is there any general socket available for applications ?

No, there is not.

> I am connecting with the socket when the user is in chat and they get disconnected with socket when they leave chat and move to some other page.

Yes, all browsers disconnect when the web page closes.